# shipping method radio button not updating after calculating shipping and Update totals

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having this weird issue on my cart page. So there is two shipping method on my website. when user selects flat rate shipping and calculate the shipping charge and Update Total from a calculator, A radio buttons to select the shipping method is not updating. 
Even after updating the totals via calculator it remains selected local pickup method instead of flat rate method we selected before.

We haven't done any customizations. Is it default woocommerce behavior? I am getting zero warnings or error in console as well.

**screenshot:** https://gmkr.io/s/599054dbe096b9717aa29a3e/0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your checkout page is excluded from all WordPress page caches.

Comment: I haven't added any cache plugin or setup cache for website yet.